# I want to do a Web Slide Transaction

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I create a slide transaction for a web page using **Cascading Style Sheet** and **java script**?

Comment: Use [CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FTutorials%2FUsing_CSS_animations) or [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/).

Comment: what have you tried so far? If you do not post your code we can not help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jQuery](http://jquery.com) is the easiest with flash but with keyframes in css3 with no flash are your choices.

Example code :

```
<html>
<head><title>Slide transaction</title><head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(window).ready(function(){
$("#btn").click(function(){
 $(".slide1").animate({
  width : 'toggle'
 },1000,function () { $(".slide2").animate({
  width : 'toggle'
 },1000);});
 });
 });
 </script>
 <style>
 .slide1 {
  background-color : yellowgreen;
  width:100%;
  height : 250px;
  display : block;
  }
  .slide2 {
  background-color : darkblue;
  width : 100%;
  height : 250px;
  display: none;
  }
  </style>
  <body>
  <div class="slide1">
  This is slide 1.
  </div>
  <div class="slide2">
  This is slide 2
   </div>
   <input type="button" id="btn" value="Click Me!" style="position:absolute;top:400px;"/>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the reveal.js library which uses javascript and css to create slideshows. http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/#/

it has options to slide fade zoom or spin each slide.

To create each a slideshow with two slides markup is as follows:

```
 <div class="reveal">

            <!-- Any section element inside of this container is displayed as a slide -->
            <div class="slides">
                <section>
                    <h1>Slide Title</h1>
                    <p>Slide content goes here</p>
                </section>

                <section>
                    <h1>Slide Title</h1>
                    <p>Slide content goes here</p>
               </section>

            </div>

        </div>
```